# @section not rendering in Razor - MVC C# .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to output some additional `<head>` metadata in views which are rendered using `Html.RenderPartial()` via a shared `Partial View`.

My `_Layout.cshtml` looks like this:

```
<head>
    //...
    @if (IsSectionDefined("AdditionalMeta")) { 
        RenderSection("AdditionalMeta"); 
    }
    //...
</head>
```

...My shared view (`_Title.cshtml`) looks like this:

```
@model TitleViewModel

@section AdditionalMeta {
    @if (Model != null && Model.Title != null)
    {     
        //additional <meta> tags using Model properties here  
    }
}

//...other irrelevant code
```

...And `Index.cshtml` view implementing `_Title.cshtml`:

```
@model TitleViewModel

@{
    Html.RenderPartial("_Title", Model);
}
```

This outputs nothing though as `IsSectionDefined("AdditionalMeta")` in `_Layout.cshtml` returns `false` - I've tried moving the "AdditionalMeta" `@section` to `Index.cshtml` instead - this makes `IsSectionDefined("AdditionalMeta")` in `_Layout.cshtml` return `true` but gives the following error:

> The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml": "AdditionalMeta".

Am I missing something or approaching this the wrong way? Thanks!

EDIT: Faby's solution is correct, provided that the "AdditionalMeta" `@section` is declared in `Index.cshtml` rather than `_Title.cshtml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try with just

```
RenderSection("AdditionalMeta", false);
```

instead of

```
@if (IsSectionDefined("AdditionalMeta")) { 
    RenderSection("AdditionalMeta"); 
}
```

refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/gg537886(v=vs.118).aspx) for documentation

Comment: yes, I initially had `@RenderSection("AdditionalMeta", required: false)`

Comment: your solution is correct provided that the "AdditionalMeta" `@section` is declared in `Index.cshtml` rather than `_Title.cshtml`